# Confusion in database relationship

Tags: sql

Suppose i have created table1 as follows

```
Table1(t1id,tname)
```

and table2 as follows

```
Table2(t2id,tdescription,t1id)
```

where Table2's t1id is relating the table1 and Table2(foreighn key)
NOw i have inserted 1 row in both of the table as follows

```
Table1:->1,piklu
Table2->0,goodboy,1
```

Now suppose if we delete the first table's row will the corresponding row of second tale be deleted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you specified `ON DELETE CASCADE` for the foreign key:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms186973(v=sql.105).aspx

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the Cascading options, you can read more information in the [mysql official docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html).
For instance, if you want to automatically delete the related entry, you can use  `ON DELETE CASCADE` after the FK declaration